# terrascan pre-commit hook reports false positive alert

Tags: terraform

I need some assistance with terrascan and pre-commit hook.

terrascan reports "failed" even though there is no policy violation?

```
terrascan................................................................Failed
- hook id: terrascan
- exit code: 4

Scan Summary -

        File/Folder         :   /azure_modules/terraform-azurerm-acr
        IaC Type            :   terraform
        Scanned At          :   2021-10-04 07:42:02.6301449 +0000 UTC
        Policies Validated  :   1
        Violated Policies   :   0
        Low                 :   0
        Medium              :   0
        High                :   0


Scan Summary -

        File/Folder         : /azure_modules/terraform-azurerm-acr/examples
        IaC Type            :   terraform
        Scanned At          :   2021-10-04 07:42:02.635467 +0000 UTC
        Policies Validated  :   1
        Violated Policies   :   0
        Low                 :   0
        Medium              :   0
        High                :   0


Scan Summary -

        File/Folder         :  /azure_modules/terraform-azurerm-acr
        IaC Type            :   terraform
        Scanned At          :   2021-10-04 07:42:02.6844968 +0000 UTC
        Policies Validated  :   1
        Violated Policies   :   0
        Low                 :   0
        Medium              :   0
        High                :   0


Scan Summary -

        File/Folder         :   /mnt/c/azure_modules/terraform-azurerm-acr
        IaC Type            :   terraform
        Scanned At          :   2021-10-04 07:42:02.6743944 +0000 UTC
        Policies Validated  :   1
        Violated Policies   :   0
        Low                 :   0
        Medium              :   0
        High                :   0
```

My pre-commit YAML file is like below:

```
cat .pre-commit-config.yaml
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/gruntwork-io/pre-commit
  rev: v0.1.14
  hooks:
    - id: tflint
      args:
        - "--module"
        - "--config=.tflint.hcl"
    - id: terraform-validate
    - id: terraform-fmt
    - id: markdown-link-check
- repo: git://github.com/antonbabenko/pre-commit-terraform
  rev: v1.51.0
  hooks:
    - id: terraform_tfsec
    - id: terraform_docs
    - id: checkov
    - id: terrascan
```

How to have it resolved?

Comment: seems to be a problem with [terrascan](https://github.com/accurics/terrascan#list-of-possible-exit-codes) and not pre-commit -- 4 is "scan summary has errors but no violations"

Comment: Hi Anthony, Thanks. I asked around on their Disord channel but have had no response so thought to post here...

Answer (score 2):

The following code works perfectly fine.

**Issue**: terrascan scans all your directories for terraform files so if it does not find any terraform file it will report as errors.

```
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/gruntwork-io/pre-commit
  rev: v0.1.14
  hooks:
    - id: tflint
      args:
        - "--module"
        - "--config=.tflint.hcl"
    - id: terraform-validate
    - id: terraform-fmt
    - id: markdown-link-check
- repo: git://github.com/antonbabenko/pre-commit-terraform
  rev: v1.52.0
  hooks:
    - id: terraform_tfsec
    - id: terraform_docs
    - id: checkov
#    - id: terrascan
- repo: https://github.com/accurics/terrascan
  rev: v1.10.0
  hooks:
    - id: terraform-pre-commit
      args: [ '-i terraform --non-recursive examples/docs/']
```

Note: I have added **--non-recursive** and added **example/docs** to tell terrascan not to scan that directory as it has no  terraform file(s)